# Voltage regulator current and heating

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, temperature

Many texts I read take (Vin - Vout)*Iload i.e the current Iload is I3 in the below figure when calculating temperature of a regulator:

[image]

But I3 is not exactly same with I1 there is something called "quiescent current". Check out my previous question:
[Voltage regulator and Kirchhoff current law](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/226297/voltage-regulator-and-kirchhoff-current-law)

So would you take I1 or I3 if you were to calculate the temperature of a regulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 7805 has a quiescent current of about 5mA so with an input voltage of say 15V this is a power of 75 mW and enough to scorch (a little bit) most 0603 size resistors. But the 7805 is a T0-220 package and so it might get a little warmer but this small temperature rise is insignificant compared with the 10 volts dropped at maybe 500 mA load current i.e. 5 watts.

75 mW is 1.5% of 5 watts.

Comment: But in an exam paper you would take I1 right for more precision??

Comment: I'm not planning on sitting an exam on this!!

Comment: just wanted to mean for more precise calculation, me neither no exam lol

Comment: If you were planning to take an exam then yes, technically using Iinput for the calculations would be slightly more _correct_ but then you'd probably also have to explain why you used it instead of Iload

Comment: @Andyaka is it correct to use Iq * Vi for the power? I thought the GND was tied to the output of a voltage regulator which would make it Iq * Vo?

Comment: @Hayman So are you confused between: (Vin - Vout) * I1 and [ (Vin - Vout) * I3 + Vin * Iq ]

Comment: I'm just trying to make certain on whether the power dissipated by the quiescent current uses Vin or Vout. It's only a flat difference of 25mW so it's negligible I just wanted to probe @Andy as he's a lot more knowledgeable than me

Comment: @user16307 power in to the device with the output disconnected is Vin * Iin where Iin is the quiescent current i.e. the current that is solely used by the internals of the regulator.

Comment: @Andyaka Alright so it is more logical to use  [ (Vin - Vout) * I3 + Vin * Iq ] when calculating the precise temperature? Would you agree?

Comment: the weird thing is i coudnt find any source about this issue in all web

Comment: @user16307 It's probably better to think of package dissipation being power_in minus power_out. Power_in is Vin * Iin and power_out is Vout * Iout. In is of course Iout minus Iq.

Comment: @Andyaka I think you meant In  = Iout + Iq ? not minus Iq. And if so it becomes: [ (Vin - Vout) * Iout + Vin * Iq ]  again

Comment: Yeah I meant plus do'h!!

Answer (score 2):

The temperature of the voltage regulator is going to be affected by all current flowing through the regulator. However saying [image: equation 1] makes a lot more sense than using [image: Iinput].

This can only be done because the quiescent current is negligible. For example, if you've got a quiescent current of 6mA and an output of 100mA (I'm using an L7805 again) with an input voltage of 12V then your power dissipated is going to be 700mW using [image: Iinput] and 742mW using [image: Iinput] where [image: Iinput], this is a 42mW difference, looking at the thermal data this is going to be a difference in case temperature of 0.21 Celsius and a difference in junction temperature of 2.1 Celsius, which is beyond negligible.

Comment: i got your point